# Different typesets for labeling within one project

Tags: qgis, labeling, internationalization

I'm searching a way to show labels with a Western typeset, as well as a different one.

In my case that's Western (English/German/...) PLUS Russian, which I don't speak at all.  But I'd like to be able to display the native labels - for example names of cities.

My idea was to use a second layer and join both, but I can't find a way :-(

Not that I can't find a way to join, but have Cyrillic displayed :-/

QGIS doesn't seam to save/recall if the typeset is changed.
Layer->Settings->Labelling->Font->Typeset

Please "suggest" a menu path - I'm not a native speaker of either, nor do I use the English version of QGIS.

Comment: Can you share some file for test purposes? (Upload it to some web space and post the link here.)

Comment: If would be able to upload sample file, the question would already been answered/solved ;-)

Just think of a point layer with georeferenced city names (english), plus a table which is not gereffernced and holds the correct cyrillic city names. Both joint by some kind of index.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bugreport for QGIS (OS X) on fonts, where there was pointed out that Qt has a bug in referrence to fontselection, some fonts simply replacing by Helvetica
or resetting everything to default.
So far given solution: Try an other font!
The error doesnt seam to show up on native language installations.

After downloading and testing a lot of cyrillic fonts I now do have cyrillic labeld layers beside the standard english ones at my german language QGIS.